# How can I have two Bootstrap navbars on the same page of different heights?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Using Bootstrap 3.0 with two navbars on the same page. The height variable will adjust both .navbar blocks. I've tried adding another class to override the height of the first navbar, but its left unaffected.

[Bootply example](http://bootply.com/93713)

HTML:

```
<!-- Site Tools and Search Navbar -->
<div class="navbar siteTools">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Site Tool Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Site Tool Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Site Tool Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Primary Navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu #1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu #2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu #3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu #4 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu #5 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu #6 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>        
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.siteTools {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color:#cdcdcd;
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: this is probably because the contained elements keep the height to height minimum. try changing the contained elements heights as well (or paddings/margins, etc)

Comment: Yup.  If you override they're min-height style then it remains the same height because of the padding on the `<a>`

Comment: I knew I must have missed something simple! This does not affect the link tags within the navbar, so I'm guessing I'll have to just add override classes to adjust those as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the other answer has already been marked correct, but I don't think that specifying a height is the correct way to fix this.

Even if you override the default min-height and set it to 0, the menu is still tall, and that's because of the padding and margins of the elements inside that navbar.  By explicitly setting `height: 35px` you'll be cutting of the content inside the navbar at 35px.  This looks bad and is not great for anyone wanting bigger font sizes etc.

I think you should adjust the elements inside the navbar instead like this:

```
.siteTools {
  min-height:0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color:#cdcdcd;
  border:none;
}

.siteTools .nav > li > a {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.siteTools form[role="search"] {
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.siteTools form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  height: 25px;
}

.siteTools form[role="search"] button[type="submit"] {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

[Working demo here.](http://bootply.com/93758)

Comment: Of course you are right and your answer is also correct. But thing was only "why its not changing" thats why my answer was so simple. Question author did not asked to correct entire styling for him;) thats his job to correct as he wants it ;)

Comment: I just thought that your answer would encourage the OP to put the `height: 35px` in their CSS, which would be solving one problem only to create another.

Comment: Both great answers. Thanks! @scx started me in the right direction. Either way I was stumbling around trying to figure out both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. min-height is blocking shrinking your element bellow its value.

```
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
div.siteTools.navbar {
  height:35px;
  min-height:35px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color:#cdcdcd;
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: If you explicitly set a height you'll cut off the menu at 35px.  Better to adjust the padding around the `<a>` tags and the search form.

Comment: Its only an example to show how to change its height, its not his final styles for the project ;)

Comment: True, it is an example. I just think if the OP is a beginner, then bad practice is being encouraged with the suggestion of declaring a height on the navbar container.